# Have a complex DAX challenge and need some advise how to solve it

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: Problem overview]

Hi! I have challenge in Power BI constructing what you see in the picture. Briefly explained, I need to be able to trace the fish. The fish stocking will be put into cages but here we will also put them into what we call fishgroups. A fishgroup is just a defined period of time the fish stay in the group (start,end). A new status is created each day counting how many fish is still alive. After a while the fish is growing and must be sorted and new fish groups are created. In the picture there are 4 fishgroups where fish is put into FG1 and FG3. After some days FG1 is sorted and 60% is sent to FG2 and 40% sent to FG4. In FG3 is all fish moved to FG4. FG1 and FG3 ends here. FG2 ends when fish are sold. The same happends later for FG4.

Perhaps I need to explain how this should work. Below I have written out the content of the tree important tables (small amount of data of course)

Let us start what is happen. When the fish is put out it will create the first Fish Group row in the FishGroup dimension, the start date will be known, it will create a row in the fact table saying 1000 fish are in stock. It will also create a row in the bridge table saying the qty factor is 1 where destination FG and source FG are the same. The next days the number of fish in stock changes giving new status in the fact table but the calculation has the same factor.

The 2.1.2019 we are setting out 1000 fish into FG3, a new row is inserted to fishgroup table, likewise to a new row into the fact table and also the bridge table with qty factor 1 and dest and source fishgroup are the same for the new fishgroup 3. There are now two fishgroups 1 and 3.

Everything goes as normal until we are coming to 5.1.2019 (dd.mm.yyyy), then things change. Two new fishgroups are created FG2 and FG4. We are splitting out fishgroup 1 sending 60% of the content to FG2 and 40% to FG4. Likewise is 100% of FG3 sent to FG4. The interesting thing here is what is happening in the bridge table. Destination FG 2 has 60% of content from FG1, but also 100% of its self. FG4 has 40%of the content of FG1 and has 100% of content of FG3 and 100% of itsself. In a report from 1.1.2019 to 4.1.2019 only fishgroup 1 and 3 will be in it. if the report will span from 1.1.2019 to 11.01.2019 all fishgroups will be in it, but the measure must find the right number of fish. There must not be any double counting as can be in the 5.1.2019. And the last timestamp each day is the only valid.

Fact Table

```
| Date Key | Cage Key | Fishgroup Key | StatusTime                  | FishGroupId                          | NumberOfFish | StatusType |
|----------|----------|---------------|-----------------------------|--------------------------------------|--------------|------------|
| 20190101 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1000         | 0          |
| 20190102 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 990          | 1          |
| 20190103 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 980          | 1          |
| 20190104 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 970          | 1          |
| 20190105 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 960          | 1          |
| 20190105 | 1        | 1             | 2019-01-05 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 955          | 2          |
| 20190105 | 1        | 2             | 2019-01-05 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 573          | 0          |
| 20190106 | 1        | 2             | 2019-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 568          | 1          |
| 20190107 | 1        | 2             | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 558          | 1          |
| 20190108 | 1        | 2             | 2019-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 548          | 1          |
| 20190108 | 1        | 2             | 2019-01-08 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 543          | 2          |
| 20190102 | 2        | 3             | 2019-01-02 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1000         | 0          |
| 20190103 | 2        | 3             | 2019-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 985          | 1          |
| 20190104 | 2        | 3             | 2019-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 970          | 1          |
| 20190105 | 2        | 3             | 2019-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 955          | 1          |
| 20190105 | 2        | 3             | 2019-01-05 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000003-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 948          | 2          |
| 20190105 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-05 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1330         | 0          |
| 20190106 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1320         | 1          |
| 20190107 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1310         | 1          |
| 20190108 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1300         | 1          |
| 20190109 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-09 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1290         | 1          |
| 20190110 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-10 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1280         | 1          |
| 20190111 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-11 00:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1270         | 1          |
| 20190111 | 2        | 4             | 2019-01-11 12:00:00.0000000 | 00000004-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 1265         | 2          |
```

FishGroup Dimension Table

```
| FishGroup   Key | Cage Key | StartTime        | EndTime          | FishgroupName | FishGroup Start Date Key | FishGroup End Date Key | IsDelivery |
|-----------------|----------|------------------|------------------|---------------|--------------------------|------------------------|------------|
| 1               | 1        | 01/01/2019 12:00 | 05/01/2019 12:00 | B-001.000001  | 20190101                 | 20190106               | 0          |
| 2               | 1        | 05/01/2019 12:00 | 08/01/2019 12:00 | B-001.000002  | 20190105                 | 20190109               | 1          |
| 3               | 2        | 02/01/2019 12:00 | 05/01/2019 12:00 | B-001.000003  | 20190102                 | 20190106               | 0          |
| 4               | 2        | 05/01/2019 12:00 | 11/01/2019 12:00 | B-001.000004  | 20190105                 | 20190112               | 1          |
```

TraceBack Bridge Table

```
| Qty Factor | Destination FishGroup Key | Source FishGroup Key |   |
|------------|---------------------------|----------------------|---|
| 1          | 1                         | 1                    |   |
| 0.6        | 2                         | 1                    |   |
| 1          | 2                         | 2                    |   |
| 1          | 3                         | 3                    |   |
| 0.4        | 4                         | 1                    |   |
| 1          | 4                         | 3                    |   |
| 1          | 4                         | 4                    |   |
```

What I need help to is to construct a DAX Measure that when summarize on each day  you get what you see in the End of Day column. The picture shows a thought Matrix visualization example (except the arrows). When adding Fishgroups into column, it should separate the content in each column but still sum correct.

For now I have tried solving this using a bridge table[image: datamodel] And here is my DAX code. I also have the Power BI file if someone is interested to look at it. Perhaps that will be more easy. I don't know how to upload a file here but can share it here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnHMZqeRJMuloW_-10_HFKatGPwu?e=FNK48d

```
Number Of Fish UB = 
VAR dato =
    MAX ( 'DateView'[Date Key] )
RETURN
SUMX (
    VALUES ( BiomassView[Cage Key] ),
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( BiomassView[NumberOfFish]) ,
    'BiomassView'[Date Key] <= dato)
)

Number Of Fish UB Base = CALCULATE([Number Of Fish UB],
ALL('DateView'))

(End) Number Of Fish UB Source FishGroups = SUMX (
  VALUES('TraceBackView'[Source FishGroup Key]),
    CALCULATE (
        [Number Of Fish UB]
            * [(End) Qty Factor],
                    LASTDATE('DateView'[Date]) )
)

(End) Number Of UB = 
VAR dato =
    MAX ( 'DateView'[Date Key])
RETURN
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( 'CageView'[Cage Key] ),
        CALCULATE (
             IF (
                    [Number Of Fish UB Cage Filter] > 0,
                    CALCULATE (
                        [(End) Number Of Fish UB Source FishGroups],
                        FILTER (
                            VALUES ( 'FishGroupView'[FishGroup End Date Key] ),
                            'FishGroupView'[FishGroup End Date Key]
                                = MAX ( 'FishGroupView'[FishGroup End Date Key] )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            'FishGroupView'[FishGroup Start Date Key] <= dato ,
            'DateView'[Is Current Day] = "Earlier"  
        )
    )
```

The SQL Source code is below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FishDim](
    [FishGroup Key] [bigint] NULL,
    [Cage Key] [bigint] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [FishgroupName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FishGroup Start Date Key] [int] NULL,
    [FishGroup End Date Key] [int] NULL,
    [IsDelivery] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FishFact]    Script Date: 23/08/2019 15:39:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FishFact](
    [Date Key] [int] NULL,
    [Cage Key] [bigint] NULL,
    [Fishgroup Key] [bigint] NULL,
    [StatusTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [NumberOfFish] [float] NULL,
    [StatusType] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TraceDim]    Script Date: 23/08/2019 15:39:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TraceDim](
    [ForwardShareCount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Destination FishGroup Key] [bigint] NULL,
    [Source FishGroup Key] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishDim] ([FishGroup Key], [Cage Key], [StartTime], [EndTime], [FishgroupName], [FishGroup Start Date Key], [FishGroup End Date Key], [IsDelivery]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-01T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'B-001.000001', 20190101, 20190106, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishDim] ([FishGroup Key], [Cage Key], [StartTime], [EndTime], [FishgroupName], [FishGroup Start Date Key], [FishGroup End Date Key], [IsDelivery]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-01-08T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'B-001.000002', 20190105, 20190109, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishDim] ([FishGroup Key], [Cage Key], [StartTime], [EndTime], [FishgroupName], [FishGroup Start Date Key], [FishGroup End Date Key], [IsDelivery]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-02T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'B-001.000003', 20190102, 20190106, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishDim] ([FishGroup Key], [Cage Key], [StartTime], [EndTime], [FishgroupName], [FishGroup Start Date Key], [FishGroup End Date Key], [IsDelivery]) VALUES (4, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-01-11T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'B-001.000004', 20190105, 20190112, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190101, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-01T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1000, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190102, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 990, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190102, 2, 3, CAST(N'2019-01-02T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1000, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190103, 2, 3, CAST(N'2019-01-03T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 985, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190103, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-03T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 980, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190104, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-04T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 970, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190104, 2, 3, CAST(N'2019-01-04T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 970, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 2, 3, CAST(N'2019-01-05T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 955, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-05T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 960, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 955, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 573, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 2, 3, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 948, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190105, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-05T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1330, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190106, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-06T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1320, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190106, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-06T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 568, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190107, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-07T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 558, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190107, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-07T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1310, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190108, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-08T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1300, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190108, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-08T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 548, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190108, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-08T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 543, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190109, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-09T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1290, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190110, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-10T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1280, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190111, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-11T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1270, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FishFact] ([Date Key], [Cage Key], [Fishgroup Key], [StatusTime], [NumberOfFish], [StatusType]) VALUES (20190111, 2, 4, CAST(N'2019-01-11T12:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), 1265, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (0.6, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (0.4, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (1, 3, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (1, 4, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TraceDim] ([ForwardShareCount], [Destination FishGroup Key], [Source FishGroup Key]) VALUES (1, 4, 4)
GO
```

Comment: I think you need to break this down into a simpler question that gets to the heart of your challenge. There too much going on here for this to be a specific question.

Comment: On the 2-5-11 of jan, you have 2 rows. You calculate the total different than in other rows. As far as I can see, total fish is FG1 + FG3 or FG2 + FG4. Do I understand this correct?

Comment: Hello again. I am sorry that my case includes much information. I have now added some more explanations to the case. Perhaps it will be more clear. I have some kind of recursive thinking, but the bridge table makes the filtering and relations needed for the dax expression